# Append column [0] after usecols=[1] as an iterator for Pandas

Tags: python-2.7, csv, pandas

I have pieced together a web crawler that takes `column2` from `input.csv` using `pandas`, and uses every cell in that column as a sequential search input on a webpage. On each search, it scrapes some stuff from the webpage and then writes the results to `output.csv`.

What I would like to do is append the contents in `column1` in `input.csv` to `output.csv` for each row.

Input.csv:

```
column1   column2
927233    DE000A12BHF2
927235    DE000A12BHG0
352006    IE00BLSNMW37
```

Code:

```
import csv
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("input.csv", usecols=[1])

def crawl(isin):
    #Scrapes data from webpage

with open("output.csv", "a") as write_csv:                
    wr = csv.writer(write_csv, delimiter = ",")
    for line in column2:
        wr.writerow([column1, data])
```

I would like this Output.csv:

```
column1   column2         data
927233    DE000A12BHF2    abc123
927235    DE000A12BHG0    def456
352006    IE00BLSNMW37    ghj789
```

Should I somehow fit `column1` in the same or a new dataframe, and if so, how can make the code still use `column2` as the iterator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion you should read the entire csv as a df, then `apply` your crawl method on column2 and create the new column and then write the df to your output:

```
In [20]:
import pandas as pd
import io
# load some data
t="""column1   column2
927233    DE000A12BHF2
927235    DE000A12BHG0
352006    IE00BLSNMW37"""
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(t),sep='\s+')
df

Out[20]:
   column1       column2
0   927233  DE000A12BHF2
1   927235  DE000A12BHG0
2   352006  IE00BLSNMW37

In [22]:    
def crawl(isin):
    return 'found:' + isin
# create data column
df['data'] = df['column2'].apply(crawl)
df

Out[22]:
   column1       column2                data
0   927233  DE000A12BHF2  found:DE000A12BHF2
1   927235  DE000A12BHG0  found:DE000A12BHG0
2   352006  IE00BLSNMW37  found:IE00BLSNMW37

In [19]:
# save it    
df.to_csv("output.csv")
```

The above would be far easier than specifically loading just column2 generating some data and then having to add a single column to your csv in my opinion.

Comment: EdChum, thank you that worked well! But how do I make it add multiple columns with different variables? I.e. I want to `return` not only `data` but `data2`, `data3`, and add them to different columns in output.csv.

Comment: You could modify your crawl func to return a Series containing a list containing each new column value so something like `def crawl(x): return pd.Series([x+1, x-1]) ` and in the assignment `df[['new_col_1', 'new_col_2']] = df['columns2'].apply(crawl)` should work